# Is it possible to have hibernation enabled and more than one OS installed safely?

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot, hibernate

I understand that hibernating an OS and then booting into another may cause data loss and file system corruption, but I'd like to know if I'll still have problems if I leave hibernation enabled, while making sure I always wake from the system I hibernated (instead of booting the other one).

I want to do this because I have a laptop computer, so when it runs out of battery I won't lose any work.

I have Windows 10 installed on an eMMC (default onboard storage) and I'm planning to install Linux on a partition of a HDD, and use the rest of the HDD storage for files to be accessed for both systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not exactly *"unsafe"* in the sense that you would probably not lose data if you did this, but all the same, it is not recommended. If you do this, then it is recommendable that you don't store your files on your Windows partition, as this is the most susceptible to data loss. As such, you would never experience anything except when you boot Linux, the partition to the hibernated drive would be mounted as read only and you wouldn't be able to write anything to it. Forcing this (with ntfsfix, say) could possibly cause some corruption, but you should still be safe.

As of it, from my personal experience (I do this same thing), it is perfectly safe and possible, just remember to keep your important files on another physical partition.

I've linked some resources here (fast startup is a form of hibernation):

http://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/

https://askubuntu.com/questions/452071/why-disable-fast-boot-on-windows-8-when-having-dual-booting